# Make ftp server accessible to other computers on network? Forward lookup zone?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I would like to set up a ftp server that is accessible by both networked machines and standalone pc's. On one computer i have installed filezilla server and on that machine i am able to ftp in. The problem comes when i try and access the server from another computer.

If i enter ftp://10.... into the browser then it doesnt find the address.

Would i neet to set anything up on the server or could the problem be something else?

THanks

Comment: Firewall?  What's a standalone PC?  If it's a PC that's not networked, I think I might know what your problem is....

Comment: Yes, a pc that hasnt been joined to the domain. It could be a firewall issue as both computers on and off the domain cannot access it. Any ideas what would have to be setup on the ftp server and on the other pc's?

Comment: Yes, i have turned off the firewall on the ftp server and i can now access it. Now to work out how to allow certain ip address to access it with the firewall on.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to open port TCP 21 to allow incoming FTP connections to your Filezilla Server machine.

In order to allow certain IP addresses to access the FTP server, you can use Filezilla's IP Filter from where you can exclude IP addresses from being allowed to connect to the FTP server. Screenshot: http://georgetasioulis.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/fz14.jpg (you can go there from "Edit" -> "Settings")

So for example if you only want to allow a few IPs to connect to the server, just enter a * on the upper box (to disallow everyone of connecting) and enter the allowed IPs on the second box.
Or if you only want to deny a few IPs enter those IPs on the first box.